# Помогите расставить знаки!

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить запятые в тексте:

"Все замечательно, и репетитор нам очень нравится. Иван Иванович обучает ученика игре на гитаре, и успехи уже великолепные. Они учатся играть на инструменте, и, в процессе, проходят все, что требуется. Я очень рада, что у сына такой учитель!"

Answer (score 2):

"Все замечательно, и репетитор нам очень нравится! Иван Иванович обучает ученика игре на гитаре, и успехи уже великолепные! Они учатся играть на инструменте и в процессе проходят все, что требуется. Я очень рада, что у сына такой учитель!"

Это на мой несовершенный взгляд. Руководствуюсь не правилами, а только тектоникой текста.
Дождитесь, пожалуйста, более солидного мнения.

Comment: По-моему, у Вас всё правильно, только перед "что требуется" запятая вроде нужна.

Comment: Упс! Думаю, вы правы. :)